# How can we split a floating point number to its integer and decimal parts?

Tags: matlab, numbers, number-formatting

I want to detect float and integer parts of a number like `235.102457`.

In short want to store two parts of my number like:

```
A=235
B=102457
```

How can I split this number?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/151605-grabbing-number-after-decimal

Comment: Your question and the answer you accepted are conflicting. Do you want `B=102457`, as per the question, or `B=0.102457` as per the accepted answer? Note that obtaining the former is much more difficult.

Comment: Can you confirm you wanted  `B = 102457` and not `B = 0.102457`?

Comment: What should the output be for a negative number?

Comment: Also please detail how you want the precision of the decimal part to be set. Most answers need to know the number of digit you want to conserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work (only tested in Octave):

```
x = 235.102457
A = floor(x)
B = mod(x,1)
```

Comment: Did you test it for `x = -235.102457` ... This does not work for negative numbers. The [`fix`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) function might be more appropriate.

Comment: This technically would save `B = 0.102457`, and not as `102457` as the OP initially asked. They are probably just being unclear in their question statement, since they did accept this.

Comment: @Adriaan oh you're right, my bad! I think your method is better.

Comment: I'm not sure about "better"; if the OP wants what they asked for in the question, then yes, mine is correct. If they want what they accepted, i.e. this answer, then use this. Going through strings when pure numerics suffice is adding a lot of unnecessary overhead and calculation time.

Comment: If negative numbers are a concern, `fix` might be a better choice than `floor`

Answer (score 7):

```
x=235.102457;
tmp = strsplit(num2str(x,16),'.'); % Cast to string, split on the dot
A = str2num(tmp{1}); % = 235
B = str2num(tmp{2}); % = 102457
```

You can do this by converting the number to a string using [`num2str()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), splitting on the dot using [`strsplit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html), then convert each part back to doubles using [`str2num()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html).

Note the `16` in the call to `num2str`: by default only 4 decimal places are put in the string. Basically any high enough number will do, as long as the decimal part of your number is smaller than this. Setting it higher can increase runtime though.

---

Doing this numerically is difficult. Specifying the number of decimal places and then rounding, as other answers do, work, but have the drawback that e.g. `1.1, 1.0, 1.100` etc are treated the same. Trying to find the power recursively doesn't work, due to numerical precision:

```
x = 235.102457;
A = fix(x);
tmp = x-A;
tmp*10^6
ans =
     1.024569999999869e+05  % i.e. needs rounding

kk = 0;
while kk<32 && ~(mod(tmp,1)==0)
   tmp = tmp*10;
   kk = kk+1;
end
tmp
tmp =
     1.024569999999869e+16  % Gets a lot of floating point garbage
```

Within the loop there is no way to know when to round off, thus trying to recursively find the number of significant digits, `kk` in this case, fails (barring round-off magic which somehow manages to round without stripping off desired decimal places).

Comment: This is the more generalized method.  (+1)

Comment: Isn't `str2double` better practice?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness as MATLAB keeps warning me about: yes in case you want double numbers. I like `str2num` though, because it is more general, as it can give various outputs. In this case, `str2num()` with output set as integer is actually possible and would reduce output size enormously, since all numbers are integers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This should work even with negative numbers:

```
nDecimalDigit = 9 ;

A = fix( x ) ;
B = round( abs(x-A) * 10^nDecimalDigit ) ;
```

The [`fix()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) function rounds towards zero, which will return the same integral part for a number whether it is negative or positive (unlike `floor` or `ceil` which round respectively toward minus infinity and plus infinity).

Since `A` preserved the sign of the original input, I guess you don't need the sign to be in the decimal part `B`, so we use `abs()` to cancel the sign.

We multiply this decimal number by a factor depending on the number of digit you want to preserve, then we do a final rounding to trim the decimal part remaining in the number.

Comment: This has [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394866/how-we-can-find-floating-and-integer-part-of-a-number#comment103137662_58395669) as two of the other answers: you need to know the amount of digits present, and if you enter a higher number, you get a different integer value, of by orders of magnitude.

Comment: I know that very well, but it is not a _problem_ yet as it does not violate the question. This part of the problem is not constrained in the question yet. Until the OP describe a restricted set of inputs or define the behavior to adopt for every floating point representation we can only propose "one of the million ways to do it..." Most of us familiar with floating point proposed to control the number of digit beforehand. If the OP has a better idea, I can't wait to hear it!

Comment: I concede my point. `1.1` is equal to `1.100` (barring floating point), so then the question is what OP considers "the part behind the decimal separator", because technically you could add infinite zeros behind the dot without changing the number.

Comment: Exactly! However, given the speed at which the OP has accepted an (incomplete) answer I think he never even consider that part. He just chose the first answer which was working for his specific case and I'm afraid we'll never hear about him again (not on this question at least) ...

Answer (score -1):

let's say you want to keep 6 decimal places, then you can do this:

```
x = rand * 1000;
dec = 6;
A = round(x);
B = round((x-A)*10^dec);
```

Comment: Aren't you risking `A` being off by one if it rounds upward?

Comment: Besides the off-by-one error this also doesn't generalise easily, because you already need to know the amount of decimals before being able to split it. You might as well hand-write it in the first place then.